# Hive: Unable to get summation of different categories

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

From Hive, i am trying to get the result from simple table which looks below

```
custername Prjtid Hours  Billable_Status

ABC         AB123  10     Billable

ABC         AB123  20     Non-Billable

ABC         AC123  10     Billable

ABC         AB123  30     Billable

PQR         PQ123  20     Billable

PQR         PQ123  30     Billable

PQR         PQ123  20     Non-Billable
```

Now i want to display like,

`Custername, Prjtid, (Total number of billable), (total number of non-billable).`

Example:

`ABC, AB123, 40, 20`

`PQR, PQ123, 50, 20`

I am able to get for Billable or non-billable but not together.

Could anyone please advice how to go ahead with this scenario?

Regards,

Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by should give what you need:

```
SELECT Custername, Prjtid, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Billable_Status = 'Billable' THEN Hours ELSE 0 END ),
SUM(CASE WHEN Billable_Status = 'Non-Billable' THEN Hours ELSE 0 END )
FROM table
GROUP BY Custername,Prjtid;
```

Comment: Removed unwanted group by column to get the answer!

Comment: Hmm you are wrong. After your change there will be a SemanticException! You cannot display field without an aggregating function if it is not contained in group by :/.

Comment: Ohh, Sorry, I have tested it with MySql, Please roll back, and you have added `o` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be off the the topic but the following works with Mysql,

> SELECT a.custername, a.Prjtid, a.billable_hours AS Billable
>   ,b.not_billable_hours AS NonBillable FROM (SELECT
>   custername,Prjtid,sum(Hours) AS billable_hours FROM table WHERE
>   Billable_Status='Billable' GROUP BY custername) AS a,(SELECT
>   custername,Prjtid,sum(Hours) AS not_billable_hours FROM table WHERE
>   status='Non-Billable' GROUP BY custername) AS b WHERE
>   a.custername=b.custername;